# Vue: props keep coming back as undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm checking my Root and child (Topbar) component and each time, the foo prop is undefined in each one.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong since I am defining it.

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('Topbar', 
    require('./components/Topbar.vue').default);

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        activeTab: "cart"
    },
    props: {
        foo: "testing props"
    }
})
```

**Topbar.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="tabs">
            <a v-on:click="handleClick('account')" v-bind:class="[ activeTab === 'account' ? 'active' : '' ]">Account</a>
            <a v-on:click="handleClick('cart')" v-bind:class="[ activeTab === 'cart' ? 'active' : '' ]">{{foo}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: ['activeTab'],
        data() {
            return {
                activeTab: "CCC"
            }
        },
        props: ["foo"],

    }
</script>
```

**laravel-blade-template file**

```
<div id = "app"> 
   <Topbar :foo="testing props"></Topbar>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have two `props` data in your component?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the colon in front of `foo`.

If you add the colon, then it's executed as JavaScript, and the variable `testing` doesn't exist.  If you remove the colon, then you should receive `"testing props"` as a string.

```
<div id = "app"> 
   <Topbar foo="testing props"></Topbar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems with your code.

- You are defining a prop in `app.js`. You **cannot** assign a value to it. The syntax you are using cannot be used to pass a variable. More about the syntax about declaring a prop [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types).
- In `Topbar` you are assigning a value to a prop, but are using the binding syntax. Vue will execute the following js code `testing props` which is not a valid code. You should use this `:foo="'testing props'"`. The reason for the apostrophe inside the quotes is the fact that `'testing props'` is a valid string in JS, and it will get assigned to your prop.
- You are also defining `props` 2 times in `Topbar.vue`. You'll end up with your last definition and that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I could identify two errors in your codes:

1. You should not have `props` definition in your export
2. The value `testing props` that you have assigned to `foo` is a `string` and should wrapped with `single quotes (')`.

The following codes should work:

```
export default {
    props: ['activeTab', 'foo'],
    data() {
        return {
            activeTab: "CCC"
        }
    }

}
```

And this

```
<Topbar :foo="'testing props'"></Topbar>
```